# Wamp Server Not Processing PHP properly to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

As requested by Shankar I am going to post the form code and the php code to this issue. Since yesterday I have moved over to my MAC and installed XAMPP to try to solve the problem but I am still having the same issue. Firstly here is the form code as set in text mate:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>

   <head>


   </head>


   <title>Practising my PHP</title>


    <body>
    <h2>Subscriber Form</h2>

    </body>

    <form id="subscriber" action="practice.php" method="post">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="25" border-width="0">
    <tr>
        <td><label for name="name" id="name" value="">Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" maxlength="30" maxsize="24"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label for name="email" id="email" value="">Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" maxlength="30" maxsize="24"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="reset" id="reset" value="reset"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"</td>
    </tr>   

</table>


    </form>


    </html>
```

Next we have the processing PHP code.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];

    $server = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("The Server Cannot 
     Be Accessed at This Time");
$db = mysql_select_db('practising') or die("The Database Cannot Be Accessed, 
    Please Try Again Later");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`name`,`email`) 
    VALUES ('$name','$email')");

if(empty($name) || empty($email)) {

    echo "All Fields Must Be Filled Out";

} else {

    echo "Your Information has Been Added to Our Database";
}


    }

    ?>
```

I look forward to your comments and help. Oh by the way both files are saved as .php files.

Whatever errors there are in the above can somebody please advise.

What is happening at my end is this. I open the newsletter.php page which displays the form in the browser. When I do anything like fill in one field and test for if statement to notify me that all fields must be filled in nothing happens. I just get the form processing and a bland newsprocess.php page is returned in the processor. Also there is nothing being inserted into the database. I hope that this information is clear enough if you can help me it will be much appreciated. I have also changed my copy of WAMP to 4.0.4. to see if this helps. I also open the file in the urle with the following `http://localhost/wamp/TrainingPHP/newsletter.php`

Another strange thing is if I us a `<?php echo "hello world" ?>`as a test outside of this code but on the same page then the echo returns the hello world.

Comment: Can you post the `form` code ?

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Hi Shankar and Joni I have tried Joni's idea initially but that was not the problem. I have moved over to my Mac to see if it will work in XAMPP but still the same problem. Here is a shortened version of the code. First the form code as requested by Shankar:

Comment: and in MAc you have to use password in mysql_connect as root. means your username for mysql_connect will be root and password will also be root but in windows in wamp or xampp it is kept blank.

Comment: Hi Iqbal, I have done that and I also changed my mysql to mysqli. But still not getting any satisfaction. When I fill in the form and submit I go to the process page but I do not get any echo from the statement nor does anything get inserted into the table of the database.

Answer (score 0):

change your `mysql_query` code

```
$query = mysql_query($sql, "INSERT INTO    subscribers(name,email)
VALUES('$name','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO    subscribers(name,email)
 VALUES('$name','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Remove `$sql` inside `mysql_query`

Note: Try to use Mysqli or PDO as mysql_* function will be deprecated in future versions of PHP

=========== Edit ===========

change this line `<td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"</td>`

to

```
<td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
```

1. you have missed  ending ">" for input type = submit
2. give name to the submit button like `name="submit"` as i have given. as with out name PHP will not recognize this field
3. you only have given id to the email and name fields you have to give them names. PHP do not recognize ids but it know a field by name. change your both email and name html field like this.

as

```
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="30" maxsize="24">
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30" maxsize="24">
```

Comment: Maz, I have noted your suggestion but I have tried it this way and it still did not work. I will also take on board your information regarding the mysqli use instead of mysql. Cheers. See the edited code above! Maybe you can still help me.

Comment: Hi Iqbal, just seen your other answers now. I have corrected the issues you pointed out. Thanks. My page now seems to be trying to connect to the DB but I am getting this warning: `
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practising/practice.php on line 9
The Database Cannot Be Accessed, Please Try Again Later`  Can you Advise? This is the code in the select  `MySqli_Select_db('practicing')` then it goes on to the or die() etc. Practising is the name of the Database.

Comment: Hi Iqbal, can you make any sense of this, when I click the submit and the browser moves to the processing page I get this warning now: `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/practising/practice.php on line 9` and here is the line of code that it refers to `$db = mysqli_select_db('practising') or die ("The Database Cannot Be Accessed, Please Try Again Later");`

Comment: Hi Maz, Just want to let you know that I have sorted the last issue out. It seems that using mysqli was causing me a problem (apart from the other issues) that is why I was getting the warning. I have successfully added the detail to the database. I will need to read up on my MySQL also to determine what I need to do when using mysqli. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just want to say thanks to all who contributed to helping me with this issue. Cheers. Just one more thing. Anybody able to direct me to a place where I can find a mysqli_select_db() query - now which inserts data into the database would be great! Thanks

Comment: @VinnyBrown hopefully you have sorted out the issue with script. 
If you google PHp, mysqli tutorial, you will find a lot of resources such as http://codular.com/php-mysqli and http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/.

Answer (score 0):

your PHP code is ok but you have issues in your HTML code. you need to have some more practice in HTML and there were some basic mistakes.anyways im posting working code of HTML you can use this and compare it with yours and remove mistakes in you code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>Practising my PHP</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <h2>Subscriber Form</h2>
 <form id="subscriber" action="practice.php" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="25" border-width="0">
    <tr>
        <td><label for name="name" id="name" value="">Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"  maxlength="30" maxsize="24"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label for name="email" id="email"   value="">Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" id="name" maxlength="30" maxsize="24"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="reset" id="reset" value="reset"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>   

</table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```